# Lawvere’s fixed-point theorem

Tags: diagonalization, fixed-point-theorems, foundations, philosophy

There is much discussion going on in the philosophy of mathematics regarding semantic and syntactical paradoxes. I wonder how this theorem is perceived?

Here you find more on the theorem: [https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere's+fixed+point+theorem#:~:text=Theorem%202.1.,that%20fs%3Ds](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere%27s+fixed+point+theorem#:%7E:text=Theorem%202.1.,that%20fs%3Ds)).

Comment: Can you state at least the theorem?

Comment: Have you read the reference https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305282 given in the cited nlab page? It's a nice paper, and I guess, it also attempts to answer your questions.

Comment: Yes I did, a wonderful paper. But I wonder if there is no real debate going on this...

Comment: Maybe ask the same on the philosophy site.